# Spurios wake up and condition variables

Tags: c++, boost-thread, condition-variable

I was reading this 
nice blog from A Williams:

http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/condition-variable-spurious-wakes.html

and one thing bugs me:
when thread wakes up because of the spurious wake does it have mutex locked?

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
while(the_queue.empty())
{
    the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
}
```

I guess so because otherwise  call to .empty would be unsafe but Im not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does have the mutex locked. Basically, the mutex gets released only while the thread is blocked in `the_condition_variable.wait()`. Spurious wakeup or not, the mutex is locked everywhere else in the code that you show.

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.wait) for `boost::condition_variable::wait()`:

> **Postcondition:**
>
> `lock` is locked by the current thread.